# Add items to end of Linked List gives strange result

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to add elements to end of my linked list and do not see that happening. It always seem to add None to the end of the linked list. I am not sure why this happens and I am guessing this has to do something with someone my .next setup incorrectly. I am using python to implement my linked list. Can someone please help me with this

Below is my Node class

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = None
    
    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data
        
    def get_next(self):
        return self.next
    
    def set_next(self, node):
        self.next = node
```

And here is my linked list class with insert methods

```
class SingleyLinkedList:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
    
    def insertAtHead(self, data):
        currentNode = self.head

        newNode = Node()
        newNode.set_data(data)  
        
        if currentNode != None:
            newNode.set_next(currentNode)
            self.head = newNode
            print("Inserted ", data, " at the head")
        else:
            self.head.set_next(newNode)
    
    def insertAtEnd(self, data):
        currentNode = self.head
        
        new_node = Node()
        new_node.set_data(data)
        
        while currentNode.get_next() != None:
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        
        currentNode.set_next(new_node)
        print("Inserted ", data, " at end")
    
    def printNode(self):
        print("\nPrinting the nodes")
        currentNode = self.head
        
        while currentNode.next != None:
            print(currentNode.data, " --> ", end="")
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        print(" NULL \n")

s = SingleyLinkedList()

s.insertAtHead(5)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtHead(10)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtHead(1)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtEnd(20)
s.printNode()
```

I get the below result,

> Inserted  5  at the head
>
> Printing the nodes
> 5  -->  NULL
>
> Inserted  10  at the head
>
> Printing the nodes
> 10  --> 5  -->  NULL
>
> Inserted  1  at the head
>
> Printing the nodes 1  --> 10  --> 5  -->  NULL
>
> Inserted  20  at end
>
> Printing the nodes 1  --> 10  --> 5  --> None  -->  NULL

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `self.head = Node()` in the `init` must be `self.head = None`?

Comment: Hey DYZ, I've made `self.head=None()` to initialize an empty node with both `self.data=None` and `self.next=None`. This way I just need to assign values to the data and next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you init head with `Node()` which holds `None` values which is incorrect you should have empty head that is why you see `None` at the end because it gets propagated till end and lastly you do not print the last `Node()` because the last node has no `next` This condition do not show `Node` without next:

```
    while currentNode.next != None:
        print(currentNode.data, " --> ", end="")
        currentNode = currentNode.next
```

So you need to print one more.

Below working example with small simplification:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_next(self, node):
        self.next = node


class SingleyLinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertAtHead(self, data):
        old_head = self.head
        self.head = Node(data, old_head)
        print("Inserted ", data, " at the head")


    def insertAtEnd(self, data):
        currentNode = self.head

        while currentNode.get_next() != None:
            currentNode = currentNode.next

        currentNode.set_next(Node(data))
        print("Inserted ", data, " at end")


    def printNode(self):
        print("\nPrinting the nodes")
        currentNode = self.head

        while currentNode.next != None:
            print(currentNode.data, " --> ", end="")
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        print(currentNode.data, " --> ", end="")
        print(" NULL \n")


s = SingleyLinkedList()

s.insertAtHead(5)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtHead(10)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtHead(1)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtEnd(20)
s.printNode()
```

Output:

```
Inserted  5  at the head

Printing the nodes
5  -->  NULL 

Inserted  10  at the head

Printing the nodes
10  --> 5  -->  NULL 

Inserted  1  at the head

Printing the nodes
1  --> 10  --> 5  -->  NULL 

Inserted  20  at end

Printing the nodes
1  --> 10  --> 5  --> 20  -->  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertAtEnd` is correct, but your `printNode` is incorrect.  As it is, it always replaces the last item in the linked list with `NULL`.  This is fine when you're adding items to the beginning of the list, because it is suppressing the empty `head` node you initialize the linked list with.  But when you insert items at the end of the list, that dummy node is now in the middle of the list, and will show up as `None` when you print.

```
s = SingleyLinkedList()
s.insertAtEnd(1)
s.insertAtEnd(2)
s.insertAtEnd(3)
```

prints

```
Printing the nodes
None  --> 1  --> 2  -->  NULL
```

Solution:  initialize `self.head = None`, and handle that case appropriately in your methods.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete, there are other issues with the code fragment

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is this :-

`self.head = Node()`

i.e when you instantiate the SingleyLinkedList class.You are assigning the head of the linked list object to such a node whose next is `None`.

Hence you are getting `None` in your print statement `Printing the nodes 1 --> 10 --> 5 --> None --> NULL`

Below is the correct code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_next(self, node):
        self.next = node

class SingleyLinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insertAtHead(self, data):
        newNode = Node()
        newNode.set_data(data)

        if self.head:
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode

        else:
            self.head = newNode
        print "Inserted ", data, " at the head"

    def insertAtEnd(self, data):
        currentNode = self.head

        new_node = Node()
        new_node.set_data(data)

        while currentNode.get_next() != None:
            currentNode = currentNode.next

        currentNode.set_next(new_node)
        print("Inserted ", data, " at end")

    def printNode(self):
        print("\nPrinting the nodes")
        currentNode = self.head

        while currentNode != None :
            print currentNode.data,
            print " --> ",
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        print

s = SingleyLinkedList()

s.insertAtHead(5)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtHead(10)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtHead(1)
s.printNode()

s.insertAtEnd(20)
s.printNode()
```

And the output is :

```
Inserted  5  at the head

Printing the nodes
5  --> 
Inserted  10  at the head

Printing the nodes
10  -->  5  --> 
Inserted  1  at the head

Printing the nodes
1  -->  10  -->  5  --> 
Inserted  20  at end

Printing the nodes
1  -->  10  -->  5  -->  20  -->
```